# How to unit test a route in Hottowel Angular template?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, jasmine, hottowel

I am trying to do a unit test on my admin route in the new hot-towel angular template.
I am using jasmine & phantomjs with Resharper in visual studio 2013.

I'm sure that I am doing something wrong as I am new to angular testing. The $state is always empty or null. Is there something I need to do with $state after I inject it to have a valid state?

**Here is the error I get.**

```
       Expected null to equal '/admin'.
Error: Expected null to equal '/admin'.at stack (  jasmine.js: line 1442)
```

**Admin Route Spec:**

```
///<reference path="~\app\components\angular\angular.js" />
///<reference path="~\app\components\angular\angular-route.js" />
///<reference path="~\app\components\angular\angular-ui-router.js" />
///<reference path="~\app\components\angular\angular-mocks.js" />
///<reference path="~\app\components\jasmine\jasmine.js"/>
///<reference path="~\app\blocks\router\router-helper.provider.js"/>
///<reference path="~\app\blocks\router\router.module.js"/>
///<reference path="~\app\blocks\logger\logger.js"/>
///<reference path="~\app\blocks\logger\logger.module.js"/>
///<reference path="~\app\admin\admin.module.js"/>
///<reference path="~\app\admin\admin.controller.js"/>
describe('Admin Routes', function () {
 beforeEach(module('ui.router'));
 beforeEach(module('blocks.router'));
 beforeEach(module('blocks.logger'));
 beforeEach(module('app.admin'));

 var $rootScope, $state, $injector,
         adminView = 'app/admin/admin.html',state = 'admin';

 beforeEach(function () {
    inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$state_ , _$injector_, $templateCache) {
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $injector = _$injector_;
        $state = _$state_;

        $templateCache.put(adminView, '');
      });
    });

it('should map state admin to url /admin ', function() {          
   expect($state.href(state, {})).toEqual('/admin');     
});


});
```

Answer (score 0):

dont' forget to include :

```
///<reference path="~\app\admin\admin.route.js"/>
```